# Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR) Class 'App\Providers\View' not found

Tags: laravel

Runtime  error on AppServiceProvider.php file . Following my code

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

use App\Category;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {

        View::share('name','bitm');

        View::composer('frontEnd.includes.menu',function($view){


            $publishedCategories = Category::where('publicationStatus',1)->get();

            $view->with('publishedCategories',$publishedCategories);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Anybody can help me??

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the namespace `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::share()` or

```
use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
```

**edit**

As @d3jn pointed out, the right way is just `use View;`.

Comment: Laravel registers aliases for it's facades by default, so `use View;` is also a viable and much shorter alternative in his case.

Comment: @Md.PalashAlam if `Illuminate\Support\Facades\View` is not found then you probably made a typo in your `use` statement. If you are using alias (just `use View`) then you should probably go check `aliases` in `config/app.php` and see if `View` is assigned there.